# Typescript: Is it possible to infer returned value from argument value?

Tags: typescript, type-inference

How would you implement myFunc?

```
const myObj: {prop: 'hello'} = myFunc('hello');
```

I can do this:

```
function myFunc<T = string>(value: T): {prop: T} {
    return {prop: value};
}

const obj: {prop: 'hello'} = myFunc<'hello'>('hello');
```

Is there a way to make it work without <'hello'>?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript will do inference based on return type, so for example here `T` will be inferred to hello:

```
function myFunc<T>(): { prop: T } {
    return null as any;
}

const myObj: {prop: 'hello'} = myFunc(); // T is inferred to hello if we hover  in VS Code over the call we can see this.
```

Form your question though I don't really think this is what you are looking. If you want `T` to be inferred as a string literal type you need to specify `T extends string` and then you don't need to specify an extra type annotation:

```
function myFunc<T extends string>(value: T): { prop: T } {
    return null as any;
}

const myObj: {prop: 'hello'} = myFunc('hello'); // T is inffered to hello
const myObj2  = myFunc('hello'); // T is inffered to hello, myObjs2 is typed as  {prop: 'hello'} , no types necessary
```